# Linux bash script file concatenation

Tags: linux, bash

Hi in my script i've concatenated two files into a new file called output.txt.  Am having trouble checking that output.txt file does exist to then print a "concatenation successful" message.  The concatenation appears to work and create a new file.

```sh
cat $file1 $file2 >> output.txt     

file3="$output.txt"                #incorrect?

if [ -e $file3 ]                             
then
    echo "concatenation of files successful"
fi
```

Comment: Remove the dollar sign: `file3="output.txt"`. `$output` is being replaced by a variable named output (which does not exist in the snippet posted here). If you move the file3 variable above `cat`, you can use it for the output redirection as well to avoid repeating the filename twice.

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
file3="output.txt"
cat $file1 $file2 >> $file3

if [ -f $file3 ]; then
    echo "concatenation of files successful"
fi
```

Comment: That `-f` doesn't fix the problem. In fact `-e` works just fine too.

Comment: Just fixed it - now should be ok

Comment: I changed to upvote because @cfillion only added his answer as a comment. So even though this is edited this now is the correct answer. @phebus - note that in a shell script you don't need to have `;` after `if` and before `then`

Comment: It now tries to run a command named `file3`. There should not be spaces around the equal sign.

Answer (score 1):

```
file3="output.txt"
cat $file1 $file2 >> $file3

if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    echo "concatenation of files successful"
fi
```

Checking the file's existence doesn't mean that the files concatenated successfully. It means that the file exists.

Consider that:

```
cat $file1 $file2(missing) >> $file3
cat $file1(missing) $file2 >> $file3
```

would make `$file3` exist.

Checking last operation exit value with `$?` accounts for the whole operation working successfully.

Also, unless you're specifically looking to append `>>` to existing file, you will ALWAYS append. So your file will always exist after the first operation.

Answer (score 0):

In single line

```
cat $file1 $file2 >> output.txt && echo 'Success' || echo 'Failed'
```